# Defining default value in combobox in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

```
    <?php
        echo $form->create('admin_merchant_form', array('action' => '#'));
        echo $form->input('company_name', array('label' => 'Company Name'));
        echo $form->input('ac_owner',
                           array('label' => 'Account Owner',
                           'options' => array('a','b','b'),
                           'default' => $merchant_select));
        echo $form->end('Update');
    ?>
```

This is CakePHP code to generate a form with one combobox containing the values "a,b,c" and assigning the default value as `$merchant_select` which is numerical data. Now the problem is when I assign like 'default'=>1 it returns 'b' in the combobox as default value but when writing 'default' => $merchant_select  the combobox shows only the first value which is 'a'.

The `$merchant_select` variable is assigned a numeric value equal to merchant's id which 1,2 or 3 when I select any row in the grid. And I also have JavaScript code which alerts with the merchant value when I select any row in the grid so the numeric data is definitely assigned to the `$merchant_select` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Default values are set by passing the **index** of the desired value as the 'default' parameter.  In your code, you're not using an explicitly named associative array.  What you want is something like:

```
'options' => array('a'=>'A', 'b'=>'B', 'c'=>'C'), 'default'=>'a'
```

You can use numeric keys too, you would just need 'default' to be 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: thats what i am telling. The thing you told is working. BUT if i assign some variable to default i.e.: default=>$value then it is not working.............

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is controlled automatically, but the `$merchant_id` variable might be in a string context, rather than a numeric context. Try casting it to a number to see if that changes anything.

Comment: also:http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

see the part about default values:
"Use the controller for populating the form with default values"

Answer (score 0):

'default' is a zero-based value, in your case you must assign ($merchant_select - 1), or much better: make the options array with key-values of merchants:

```
<?php

  echo $form->input('ac_owner',
    array('label' => 'Account Owner',
      'options' => array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'),
      'default' => $merchant_select));
?>
```